# Can I visit other gods' temple after have visited Saneeshwara temple (Thirunallar, Karaikkal)?

Tags: belief, shani

I have plan to visit Saneeshwara temple which is in Karaikkal , Pondicherry.
Also in the next day,  I thought to attend Maha Magam festival.

Is it OK to visit another God's temples after visiting Saneeshwara temple?

I am asking this because I heard that we should go back to home after visiting Sanneshwara temple.

Please clarify!

Comment: Seems to be an useful question.How about asking a nearby temple priest ?